# How to setup Yii2 module on subdomain correctly?

Tags: php, url, yii2, yii-url-manager

I have a project on Yii2 advances app. And I have created a module named 'sale' on front end, Where I have extended layouts of frontend. And now I just want to access that module as a subdomain like `http://sale.example.com` .

I have created subdomain `sale.example.com` and set it's document root to root folder `public_html` (sites's root folder).

I have configures my `urlManager` like `'http://sale.example.com' => 'sale/default/index',`  according to [Yii2 DOC](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#rules-with-server-names). And it working fine but all my navigation gone wrong. I mean I think app's `homeUrl` is not pointing to default site url. My entire `url` system is changed after sub domains like  `http://sale.example.com/contact`, But this is supposed to be `http://example.com/contact` .  [Here is a snapshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/81zibtciackapkx/Untitled.png?dl=0).

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you please clarify a little? You have your frontend application running under your normal URL (example.com) and you want your subdomain (sale.example.com) to be redirected to the module? So you have two frontend-parts if you want so? If this is the case I think I have your answer...

Comment: Yeah.. Lets say I have two frontend. But I have used same layouts for these frontend and modules...   I just want my module `sale` displayed as `sale.example.com`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using UrlManager. Here is example Just replace your_module_name with real name of your module. More on UrlManager you can see [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html)

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enableStrictParsing' => false,
        'rules' => [
            'sale.example.com/<controller>/<action>' => 'your_module_name/<controller>/<action>',
        ],
    ],
```